# backbone model sets value on false validate

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm learning backbone.js and trying to figure out how to use the validation method. But my problem is when I call for validation the validation is triggered but it still saves the invalid data. As seen here `player.set('firstName', '', { validate: true });` I set lastName variable to '' and it saves that values, and it shouldn't.

**Edit** - Updated code so now it works correctly
Backbone model.

```
var Player = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        firstName: "Not specified",
        lastName: "Not specified",
        position: "Not specified"
    },
    validate: function (attributes) {
        // validate first name
        if (!attributes.firstName || attributes.firstName === '') {
            return 'you must have a first name';
        }
        // validate last name
        if (!attributes.lastName || attributes.lastName === '') {
            return 'you must provide a last name.';
        }
        // validate position
        if (!attributes.position || attributes.position === '') {
            return 'you must provide a position.';
        }
    },
    initialize: function () {
        // checks when firstName has changed
        this.on('change:firstName', function () {
            console.log("firstName attribute has changed.");
        });
        // checks when lastName has changed
        this.on('change:lastName', function () {
            console.log("lastName attribute has changed.");
        });
        // checks when position has changed
        this.on('change:position', function () {
            console.log("position attribute has changed.");
        });
        // check for valid inputs
        this.on('error', function (model, error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
});
```

From within chrome dev tools I do the following code.

```
var player = new Player;
player.set({ firstName: "peter", lastName: "andrews", position: "outfield" }, { validate: true });
player.toJSON();
firstName attribute has changed. app.js:32
lastName attribute has changed. app.js:36
position attribute has changed. app.js:40
Object {firstName: "peter", lastName: "andrews", position: "outfield"}

player.set('firstName', '', { validate: true });
player.toJSON();
you must have a first name app.js:14
Object {firstName: "peter", lastName: "andrews", position: "outfield"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Backbone docs](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-validate):

> If the attributes are valid, don't return anything from validate; if
>   they are invalid, return an error of your choosing.

Your validation function is printing the error strings with `console.log` but not returning anything.

Try changing your `validate` function to something like:

```
validate: function (attributes) {
    // validate first name
    if (!attributes.firstName || attributes.firstName === '') {
        return 'you must have a first name';
    }
    // validate last name
    if (!attributes.lastName || attributes.lastName === '') {
        return 'you must provide a last name.';
    }
    // validate position
    if (!attributes.position || attributes.position === '') {
        return 'you must provide a position.';
    }
},
```

Comment: ah! haha thanks for that. Okay so another question, its working by not updating the values, but its not returning the message from the validate function. for example this `player.set('firstName', '', { validate: true });` it doesnt update but shouldn't "you must provide a last name." be returned too?

Comment: @Mr.1.0: A little bit further on the docs say "Failed validations trigger an `"invalid"` event, and set the `validationError` property on the model with the value returned by this method.".